# Webhooks for consumer notebooks only?

Tags: webhooks, onenote, onenote-api

The problem I encountered:
official documentation covers well subscribing to webhooks to get notifications of consumer notebooks. But what about enterprise apps based on Azure AD? There is said nothing about the possibility to register one's webhooks.

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks are currently only supported for consumer notebooks.

https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis

I encourage you to create/upvote an entry in our uservoice site.